# Are Spring @Scheduled cron expressions in system default timezone or UTC?

Tags: java, spring

Are the Spring `@Scheduled` [cron expressions](https://spring.io/blog/2020/11/10/new-in-spring-5-3-improved-cron-expressions) using the system default timezone or UTC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `zone` argument is not passed to `@scheduled` then it will use server's default time zone,
to change it you can send `zone` parameter like :

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0/5 * * ? * *", zone="IST")
```

Reference:[Spring Api doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html)